# Ag-grid: Update filterParams to change possible filter values

Tags: angular, ag-grid

We have a custom angular component as filter for a specific column, which lists possible filter values for that column. The possible filter values can change dynamically, and the list can get longer or shorter. So we need to update the `filterParams` of the specific `colDef`. The issue however, we have re-assign the `columnDefs` of the grid, which clears other filters and is not suitable for us. What we are looking for is something like this `gridOptions.api.setFilterModel` but to set the `filterParams` and recreate the filter component.

Only changing the filterParams of the specific `colDef` and destroying the filter does not help. When it gets re-created again, in `agInit` it receives the old `filterParams`. This is probably because the change-detection did not detect any changes in the `columnDefinition`.

Is it any way possible with ag-grid to dynamically update `filterParams` without re-assignin `columnDefs`?

Comment: I suggest you to pass `Observable<Option[]>` into the `filterParams`. Then you won't need to update the whole columnDef. You just need to pass the dynamic data into the Observable and it will reflect in your custom filter.

Comment: @DurgeshPal I'm also running into this situation. What exactly do you mean by that?
filterParams: (params) => { my code that ruturns the fliter params}. would I setup an observable that...returns each time rowdata updates? or somehow override what filterParams does and do like filterParams: this.rowData.subScribe()??

Comment: It depends how you are fetching filterParams. It may from rowData or from some api. All you need to setup an Observable that will pass to your filterParams. Observable will be subscribed automatically when the data is provided to it. You can also share minimum reproducible code on stackblitz for more understanding.

Answer (score 0):

I have that exact same thing going on, I found that updating the column defs wasn't even getting filterParams to rerun. I'm working through it now but I know that you can call the grid method:

```
gridApi.destroyFilter('colID') on each column to destroy their filters.
```

This doesn't close the filters however, and you'd have to dive into some grid methods to do that (or update colDefs). I think there's a path to getting all the filter models beforehand and attempting to re-apply them after destroying the filters but that may be going down a dark and scary rabbit hole.

Answer (score 0):

It is written [here](https://www.ag-grid.com/vue-data-grid/filter-set-filter-list/#refreshing-values) that:

> By default, when values are passed to the set filter they are only
> loaded once when the set filter is initially created. It may be
> desirable to refresh the values at a later point, for example to
> reflect other filtering that has occurred in the grid. To achieve
> this, you can call refreshFilterValues on the relevant filter that you
> would like to refresh. This will cause the values used in the filter
> to be refreshed from the original source, whether that is by looking
> at the provided values array again, or by re-executing the values
> callback.

Let's say you have `columnDefs` and `valuesForFilter` list like:

```js
valuesForFilter = ['one', 'two', 'three'];
columnDefs = [
    {
        colId: 'STATUS_CODE',
        filter: 'agSetColumnFilter',
        filterParams: {
            values: valuesForFilter,
        },
    },
];
```

If you change `valuesForFilter` list like this, your filterParams values also are going to be changed.

```js
valuesForFilter.length = 0;
valuesForFilter.push('four');
valuesForFilter.push('five');
gridOptions.api.getFilterInstance('STATUS_CODE').refreshFilterValues();
```